# How can I use Display Suite with a Drupal Commerce view?

Tags: commerce, display-suite

I am new to Display Suite and want to use it with the Drupal Commerce checkout forms. In particular for the review stage, which is made from a view.

I want to display the order summary in the left column and the customer profile address details in the right column.

I can see how Display Suite is used for regular nodes, but can not find any information about how it can be used for views fields. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the FORMAT section of the views edit page, there is a "Show:" option.

If you choose "Fields" (oftentimes the default for any Entity view, including nodes) then you cannot control the output of those fields with Display Suite.

There is an option "Rendered Entity".

You can alter the settings for this option, and select any view mode that you have created/configured with Display Suite. For example you can create a view mode "Foo", and select that view mode in the settings for the "Rendered Entity" option. This will work for any entity.

So you want to create a new view mode for your Commerce entity, select the layout of your choice, put the fields you want in the regions of your choice (maybe the two column 50/50 layout), and in your view Select "Rendered Entity" and select the proper view mode.

[image]